# How can I change the startup order of the home screen in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I have `AutoActivity` and `MainActivity`. In Manifest, `MainActivity` is the start screen.

By clicking on the button in `MainActivity`, you switch to `AutoActivity`, and it becomes the home screen.

When restarting the application, `AutoActivity` will open immediately instead of `MainActivity`.

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Have an `EntryPointActivity` that you set as your launcher activity instead of `MainActivity` in the manifest. It can delegate to one of the others. You can save the state in a `SharedPreference`.

```java
public class EntryPointActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String KEY_USE_AUTO_ACTIVITY = "KEY_USE_AUTO_ACTIVITY";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super(savedInstanceState);
        boolean useAutoActivity = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .getBoolean(KEY_USE_AUTO_ACTIVITY, false);
        Class<?> nextActivity = userAutoActivity ? AutoActivity.class : MainActivity.class;
        startActivity(Intent(this, nextActivity));
        finish();
    }
}
```

And in your button click listener in the `MainActivity`:

```java
// in onClickListener:
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).edit()
    .putBoolean(EntryPointActivity.KEY_USE_AUTO_ACTIVITY, true)
    .apply();
startActivity(Intent(this, AutoActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store a flag in `SharedPreferences`. Whenever the app runs, you can check the flag in the `onCreate()` method of the `MainActivity`. If the flag is `true`, the `AutoActivity` will be opened, and the `MainActivity` will be closed.

here is the code when clicking on the `button`:

```
Button switchButton = findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
    switchButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_AUTO_ACTIVITY_AS_HOME, true);
        editor.apply();

        startActivity(new Intent(this, AutoActivity.class));
        finish();
    });
```

here the code in `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`:

```
sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean autoActivityAsHome =
            sharedPref.getBoolean(KEY_AUTO_ACTIVITY_AS_HOME, false);
    if (autoActivityAsHome) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AutoActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

here is the complete code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
static final String KEY_AUTO_ACTIVITY_AS_HOME = "AUTO_ACTIVITY_AS_HOME";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean autoActivityAsHome =
            sharedPref.getBoolean(KEY_AUTO_ACTIVITY_AS_HOME, false);
    if (autoActivityAsHome) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AutoActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    Button switchButton = findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
    switchButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_AUTO_ACTIVITY_AS_HOME, true);
        editor.apply();

        startActivity(new Intent(this, AutoActivity.class));
        finish();
    });
}
```

}

if you want get back to the previous state, you can just delete the flag in `AutoActivity()` like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean autoActivityAsHome = sharedPref.getBoolean(KEY_AUTO_ACTIVITY_AS_HOME, false);
    if (autoActivityAsHome) {
        // Clear the flag
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.remove(KEY_AUTO_ACTIVITY_AS_HOME);
        editor.apply();
    }
```